# draw 1/2 or 1/4 equal line width circle line with css

Tags: html, css

How to draw 1/2 or 1/4 **"equal"** line width circle with css ?
(not svg)

the whole line not equal width how to fix it
https://jsfiddle.net/ryxq1e91/

```css
.circle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    background-color: red;
}
.circle >div {
  top: 11px;
  left: 14px;
}
.circle >div {
  position: relative;

  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom-right: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-bottom-left: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-radius: 8px;      
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a quarter/half of a circle what you are trying to achieve? is it like this: http://jsbin.com/pobicaraxu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another option if you want to keep the full div, just make the borders that you don't want `transparent`. The only caveat is that it will appear 45 degrees rotated, so just transform it with a `transform: rotate(45deg)`.

Note that I'm unsure what the support for this is.

## 1/4 Circle

```css
.circle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;

    background-color: red;
}
.circle >div {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.circle >div {
  position: relative;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

## 1/2 Circle

```css
.circle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;

    background-color: red;
}
.circle >div {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.circle >div {
  position: relative;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help??

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 height:45px;
    width:90px;
 margin-top:0px;
 border:2px solid black;
 border-bottom:none;
}
 
.quarter-circle {
    height:45px;
    width: 45px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
 border:2px solid black;
 border-bottom:none;
 border-right:none;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="quarter-circle"></div>
```

I decided it would be fun to turn this into a loading icon.

```css
 
.quarter-circle {
    height:45px;
    width: 45px;
 
 -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
 border:2px solid rgba(0,0,200,.5);

 border-bottom:none;
 border-right:none;
 
 
}



@-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating" style="width:90px;height:90px;"><div class="quarter-circle"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` properties to round the corners on the box according to the box's height (and added borders).

Then add a border to top/right/left sides of the box to achieve the effect.

**1 / 2 Circle**

```css
.half-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border: 10px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;
    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

**1 / 4 Circle**

```css
.half-circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border: 10px solid gray;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

Comment: Remember this will not work on Internet Explorer 8 or Opera Mini because of border-radius http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: thanks for reply, I update my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ryxq1e91/1/  , don't know why there's different?  how to remove left and right vertical line

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ozvfgnr/

A full circle with border and border-radius that is overlayed by elements that cut off the parts you don't want and which have the same background color.

```
<div class="circle">
   <div class="overlay1"></div>
  <div class="circlebasis"></div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
   <div class="overlay2"></div>
   <div class="overlay3"></div>
  <div class="circlebasis"></div>
</div>
```

.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.circlebasis {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(40,40,40,1);
  border-radius: 22px;

```
}
.overlay1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:1;
}
.overlay2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:1;
}
.overlay3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```